# How to create a matplotlib legend entry with 2 points (open and filled) which are horizontally aligned?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a single legend entry that shows two markers, one of them open, the other filled. I have tried to do this with both `plt.scatter` and `plt.plot` but I'm running in to trouble with either:

- With `plt.scatter`: there appears to be a slight vertical offset between the points in the legend when using `scatterpoints > 2`.  Is it possible to have them on the same horizontal?
- With `plt.plot`: Is possible to modify the legend markers individually to have one open and one filled?

```
# plot random data to host the legend:

# scatter option
plt.scatter(-1, -1,
            facecolor='k', edgecolor='k', 
            label='scatter')
# plot option
plt.plot(-1, -1, lw=0, 
         marker='o', markerfacecolor='k', markeredgecolor='k', label='plot')

# add legend
leg = plt.legend(scatterpoints=2, numpoints=2)

# modify scatter points -- have an unwanted vertical offset?
leg.legendHandles[1].set_facecolors(['None', 'k'])
leg.legendHandles[1].set_edgecolors(['k', 'k'])

# modify plot points -- cannot change individual markers?
leg.legendHandles[0].set_markeredgecolor(['None', 'k'])
leg.legendHandles[0].set_markeredgecolor(['k', 'k'])
```

[image: Attempt to create legend with open and filled points]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to align the scatterpoints horizontally by setting the `scatteryoffsets` parameter of `plt.legend`:

```
leg = plt.legend(scatterpoints=2, scatteryoffsets=[0.5])
```

From the [Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend):

> **scatteryoffsets** : iterable of floats
>
> The vertical offset (relative to the font size) for the markers created for a scatter plot legend entry. 0.0 is at the base the legend text, and 1.0 is at the top. To draw all markers at the same height, set to `[0.5]`. Default is `[0.375, 0.5, 0.3125]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`HandlerTuple`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple

l1, = plt.plot(-1, -1, lw=0, marker="o",
               markerfacecolor='k', markeredgecolor='k')
l2, = plt.plot(-0.5, -1, lw=0, marker="o",
               markerfacecolor="none", markeredgecolor='k')

plt.legend([(l1, l1), (l1, l2)], ["test 1", "test 2"], handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(2)})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That HandlerTupleHorizontal class is overkill. I edited the answer accordingly.